# Draw Lines on View according to phone orientations

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, orientation, catransform3d

Wanted to make an application which will draw lines on view in direction where phone is moving or orientations taking place.
like if i'll move my phone from left to right it'll draw line on my phone from left to right.
Code i have tried is:

```
motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
if (motionManager.deviceMotionAvailable)
{
    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                            withHandler: ^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {

                                                CATransform3D transform;

                                                transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(motion.attitude.pitch, 1, 0, 0);

                                                transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform,motion.attitude.roll, 0, 1, 0);

                                                transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform,motion.attitude.yaw, 0, 0, 1);

                                                self.axisLbl.layer.transform = transform;

                                            }];
}
```

but it is only moving object on its own axis in 360 degree.
Please help!!

Comment: This post could be helpful to check what direction is iPhone moving  using Accelerometer: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/basic-sensors-in/9781449309480/ch04.html

Comment: you could use accelerometer for this instead of deviceMotion!

Comment: @AlexKosyakov i checked your URL its about accelerometer and only telling about x,y and z axis movement of device. but my concern is something else. there is an app at app store 'Magic Plan' please see it once.

Please help!!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri
how can i draw a line whenever i move my phone to any direction. or when i'll move my device in 360 degree a line will be drawn.